# python regex: match the dot only, not the letter before it

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I have a regex pattern as follows:

```
r'(?:(?<!\.|\s)[a-z]\.|(?<!\.|\s)[A-Z]\.)+'
```

and I am trying to modify that so it only matches the dot at the end of the sentences and not the letter before them. here is my string:

```
sent = 'This is the U.A. we have r.a.d. golden 13.56 date. a better date 34. was there.'
```

and here is what i have done:

```
import re
re.split(r'(?:(?<!\.|\s)[a-z]\.|(?<!\.|\s)[A-Z]\.)+', sent)
```

however what happens is that it removes the last letter of the words:

```
current output:
['This is the U.A. we have r.a.d. golden 13.56 dat',' a better date 34. was ther',
 '']
```

my desired output is:

```
['This is the U.A. we have r.a.d. golden 13.56 date',' a better date 34. was there',
 '']
```

i do not know how I can modify the pattern to keep the last letter of the words 'date', and 'there'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern can be reduced to and fixed as

```py
(?<=(?<![.\s])[a-zA-Z])\.
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8JRGhK/1).

If you need to also match multiple dots, put back `+` after the `\.`.

*Details*:

- `(?<=(?<![.\s])[a-zA-Z])` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with

  - `(?<![.\s])` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `.` or whitespace immediately to the left of the current location
  - `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
- `\.` - a literal dot.

Look, your pattern is basically an alternation of two patterns, `(?<!\.|\s)[a-z]\.` and `(?<!\.|\s)[A-Z]\.`, the only difference between which is `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]`. It is clear the same alternation can be shortened to `(?<!\.|\s)[a-zA-Z]\.` The `[a-zA-Z]` must be put into a non-consuming pattern  so that the letters could not be eaten up when splitting, so using a positive lookbehind is a natural solution.